# Looping through this json data with array sub-elements

Tags: json

Basically i get a json formatted data from php. I have no control over the data that I get. A sample output is:

```
var Data={"2":[{"name":"Mr Samuel","votes":"11"}],[{"name":"Mrs Clair Cher","votes":"2"}],"3":[{"name":"Mr Madiex","votes":"13"}]};
```

The data is like this: Mr.Samuel and Mrs Clair work in a department whose id is 2, while Mr.Madiex works in department 3. The votes are the votes  they got for their performance. Now I need to loop through the data, getting name and votes.

```
 $.each(Data, function(departmentid, staffmembers){
 //departmentid is well captured: 2 and 3. But I am having a hard time going thru each departments staff members:

  $.each(Data[departmentid], function(index,value){
   //here, i expected that Data[departmentid][index].name would give me name but it is undefined.
   });


});
```

What am  I missing exactly?

Comment: You have a syntax error in the assignment to `Data`. Please fix that first so we can be sure what your JSON data structure actually is.

Comment: @trincot that's what I am getting from the php code (i have no control over it). I did ask the backend developer but he wasnt much of a help. var Data={"2":[{"staffname":"Mr Samuel Andom","votes":"11"},{"staffname":"Mrs Clair","votes":"2"}],"3":[{"staffname":"Mr Madiex","votes":"13"}]}

Comment: I just tried that, and your code works.

Comment: What seriously? Can you tell me please? I did uncomment to get "name" and "votes" but still getting undefined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the correction to the code in the original question, it seems to work (assuming you have included jQuery):

```js
var Data = {
    "2": [
        {"name":"Mr Samuel","votes":"11"},
        {"name":"Mrs Clair Cher","votes":"2"}
    ],
    "3": [
        {"name":"Mr Madiex","votes":"13"}
    ]
};

$.each(Data, function(departmentid, staffmembers){
    $.each(Data[departmentid], function(index,value){
        console.log(Data[departmentid][index].name );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, you might as well use the `staffmembers` and `value` arguments:

```js
var Data = {
    "2": [
        {"name":"Mr Samuel","votes":"11"},
        {"name":"Mrs Clair Cher","votes":"2"}
    ],
    "3": [
        {"name":"Mr Madiex","votes":"13"}
    ]
};

$.each(Data, function(departmentid, staffmembers){
    $.each(staffmembers, function(index,value){
        console.log(value.name );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Trincot! Wonderful.